# Starting up an internet company that's legally based in Delaware, U.S.A - compliance with local and foreign laws

Tags: internet, australia, delaware

I am starting a company and looking to create a C Corporation incorporated in Delaware, where we will provide online services to an Australian market.

In Australia, the services we're providing are 100% legal, but in Delaware (and most of the U.S.A) these services are not permitted by law.

My question is this (and I will follow up with an attorney to confirm):

If we register as a C Corporation incorporated in Delaware but do not have a physical presence there, and do not provide services there, must the services we provide in Australia be compliant with state and federal law inside Delaware and the U.S.A?

Comment: Why in the world would someone want to incorporate in Delaware rather than in Australia in these circumstances? So far as I know, Australia does not prohibit non-citizens from owning shares in its companies. Is the idea to try to dodge Australian tax law somehow? The nature of the service would matter too - is somebody brokering prostitution contracts or something?

Answer (score 1):

If your company is registered as a United States corp, you must comply with U.S Laws. It would probably behoove you to register the company outside of U.S. jurisdiction.. Preferably in a country where the business of your company are legal.

Answer (score -1):

US corporations must comply with US law.